# Access json data from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load/read data from a local json file using JQuery/Javascript. Everything I have tried so far is throwing me CORS policy error. I don't know how to resolve this.

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <a href="#" id="fetch">Fetch JSON</a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#fetch').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('music.json', function(data) {
          albums = data['Albums']

          console.log(albums)
        })
      });
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Json file -

```
{
  "Albums": [{
      "albumName": "Desire",
      "artist": "Bob Dylan"
    },
    {
      "albumName": "Live in London",
      "artist": "Leonard Cohen"
    },
    {
      "albumName": "Abbey Road",
      "artist": "The Beatles"
    },
    {
      "albumName": "Blackstar",
      "artist": "David Bowie"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to get this running?

Comment: Both files need to be in the same directory and you need to open the html file from the web server, not locally. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Hey ! this solved the problem ! The files were already in the same directory. I had to run it from the server and not locally. Thankss!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your project on the web server, in this case, you can do this:

**data.json**

```
{
 "albums": [
  {
   "name": "First Album",
   "artist": "Leonard Cohen"
  }
 ]
}
```

in **html** or **js** file:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5500/data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
```

in this case, my webserver local address is http://127.0.0.1:5500

Comment: Running it on server made my code work. I tried your method and it worked, too. However, now I am facing another weird problem. I changed the content of the json file and stopped and ran the server again. Now, I am not getting any result in the console ! I even cleared the cache. It just flashes the result and goes away. I don't know what to do!

Comment: It's hard to know what is the problem because your description is not enough. maybe the    reason that you not getting any result in the console is that your JSON file has a problem like missing a comma(,) or double quote(").